# if condition satisfies string, but somehow it doesn't

Tags: python

I need for user to enter a correct format of pin. So i made a code that is supposed to do that.

```
def checkPin():
    pin = input("Please enter pin: ")
    if len(pin) > 6 or len(pin) < 6:
        print("Error only 6 characters allowed")
        checkPin()  
    if pin.isdigit()==False:
        print("Error only numbers allowed")
        checkPin() 

checkPin()     
print("Entered correct format pin")
```

Then i enter an incorrect pin i get an error, so it gives me another try to enter a good format pin. Then i enter a good format pin it gives me an error, but then i enter the same good format pin like i entered in second try i don't get an error.I don't understand why it happens. Here is the output:

```
Please enter pin: abc
Error only 6 characters allowed
Please enter pin: 123456
Error only numbers allowed
Please enter pin: 123456
Entered correct format pin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the first recursive call to `checkPin` returns, you are checking the *first* input `abc` for digits, not the number entered in the recursive call.

If you use `return checkPint()`, you'll avoid unnecessarily checking the original bad input again.

```
def checkPin():
    pin = input("Please enter pin: ")
    if len(pin) > 6 or len(pin) < 6:
        print("Error only 6 characters allowed")
        return checkPin()  
    if pin.isdigit()==False:
        print("Error only numbers allowed")
        return checkPin()
```

or use `elif`

```
def checkPin():
    pin = input("Please enter pin: ")
    if len(pin) > 6 or len(pin) < 6:
        print("Error only 6 characters allowed")
        checkPin()  
    elif pin.isdigit()==False:
        print("Error only numbers allowed")
        checkPin()
```

However, you shouldn't use recursion at all simply to implement a loop.

```
def checkPin():
    while True:
        pin = input("Please enter pin: ")
        if len(pin) > 6 or len(pin) < 6:
            print("Error only 6 characters allowed")
        elif pin.isdigit()==False:
            print("Error only numbers allowed")
        else:
            break
```